# Adding bootstrap to webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I could use some helpful guidance here, brand new to webpack and chrome extensions and trying to expand on this project:

https://github.com/chibat/chrome-extension-typescript-starter

This has jquery defined and when I run npm install and npm run build the vendor.js is produced with jquery in.  I want to also use bootstrap, I changed package.json to include bootstrap as so:

```
"dependencies": {
"jquery": "~3.3.1",
"bootstrap":"^4.1.1", -- ADDED THIS
"moment": "~2.22.0"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@types/chrome": "~0.0.63",
"@types/jquery": "~3.3.1",
"@types/bootstrap":"^4.1.1", -- ADDED THIS
"ts-loader": "~4.2.0",
"typescript": "~2.8.1",
"webpack": "~4.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "~2.0.14",
"webpack-merge": "~4.1.2"
}
```

I am not sure what changes to make to webpack as there doesn't appear to be anything in there specific to jquery but when I run npm run build the vendor.js doesn't include bootstrap.

I think I am completely off here assuming package.json has a link to webpack.common.js but all my googling has found articles talking about putting import bootstrap in app.js and the chrome extension doesn't have an app.js or any lines for import jquery or anything.

Apologies to blanket ask for the answer but after a lot of googling I am no clearer and would appreciate what changes I need to make to webpack to make this work, here is the existing file:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        popup: path.join(__dirname, '../src/popup.ts'),
        options: path.join(__dirname, '../src/options.ts'),
        background: path.join(__dirname, '../src/background.ts'),
        content_script: path.join(__dirname, '../src/content_script.ts')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/js'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: "initial"
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        // exclude locale files in moment
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `require('bootstrap');` (or `import 'bootstrap';`) in one of your .js files - usually the entry file(s) - in order for it to be included with the webpack bundle. Adding to package.json doesn't automatically mean it will be included; it needs to explicitly be referenced/used.

Comment: Ah I see, so in one of the files I have import * as $ from 'jquery';  So I have added import 'bootstrap'; underneath and I can see it's now including.  Just need to get the CSS included which isn't part of this webpack, back to research.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working! I would recommend using the sass implementation of Bootstrap and basically do the same thing (import) in your main scss file.

Answer (score -1):

There is the only way how it works for me

in js scrypts add:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.jQuery = $;
global.$ = $;

import Popper from 'popper.js'
global.Popper = Popper

import 'bootstrap'

// there $.fn defined anyway
// and in chrome console too (in first way)
```

Second way (don't works):

```
// ! comment this strings
// import $ from 'jquery';
// global.jQuery = $;
// global.$ = $;

// add in config
plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
        {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'global.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'global.$': 'jquery',
        },
     ),
...
```

But if to do lower way, I don't know why, at the console on scrypt ended, $.fn undefined. It like other examplar of $ used in console and in webpack build.
Can somebody explain this?